# Как в postgresql узнать дату добавления последней записи в таблице?

Tags: sql, postgresql, дата

Как в postgresql узнать дату добавления последней записи в таблице?

Comment: Самому фиксировать данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgresql не сохраняет время, когда строки были добавлены / обновлены / удалены (это замедлило бы работу postgresql).

Вам нужно будет сделать это самостоятельно: добавьте столбец метки времени в таблицу. При вставке, изменении строки, обновите столбец, где храните время до текущего. 
Таким запросом можно будет узнать время изменения, при выполнении Вами условий выше.

```
SELECT time from yourtable ORDER BY time limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак. PostgreSQL не ведёт статистику времени изменения данных.

Если ваша цель - узнать, что таблица не используется, то необходимо сохранить вывод счётчиков использования по ней из системной таблицы [`pg_stat_all_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) (либо сбросить статистику по базе функциями `pg_stat_reset()` либо `pg_stat_reset_single_table_counters(oid)`) и посмотреть что в этих счётчиках изменилось спустя какое-то время.